# Get current post taxonomy (category) - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I've got so confused between all the different terms for taxonomy when reading up on wordpress.

I have a custom post type of car, I have a custom taxonomy of car manufactures. I would simply like to output/echo the manufacturer on the single post page.

Car manufactures taxonomy example:

- Honda

  - Civic

    - EK4
    - EK9
  - Integra

    - DC2

etc...

What code should I use so echo the taxonomy?
Looking at the above example, is there a way to echo only the parent (Honda) or child (either Civic or EK4) if I choose to?

Many thanks

S

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomy

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories#Display_Categories_Assigned_to_a_Post seems closer to what I'd like to do but I'm not sure how I'd specify if i wanted the parent, child etc

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did in the end in case it helps anyone else.

In the places where I need to show the Manufacture I would print the `name` of `$terms` object 0, if I need the Model I'd print the `name` of `$terms` object 1 etc...

```
<?php
    //Get the posts taxonomy details.
    $taxonomy = 'car_manufacturers';
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array('orderby'=>'term_order') );

    //If terms has something in it, echo what I need.
    // 0 = Manufacture
    // 1 = Model
    // 2 = Chassis Prefix
    if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        echo $terms[1]->name;
    }
?>
```